# tribonacci sequence python code skips for loop within while loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I wanted to use a for loop within a while loop to add up the last 3 numbers of the list and generate a new number to append into the existing list. However, the code would not enter the for loop within the while loop and I have no clue why.

What the function is supposed to do:

1. Take in a list of numbers (as signature)
2. Total up the LAST 3 numbers in the list and produce the next number to be appended
3. Continue step 2 until length of list == n

```
#my code

def tribonacci(signature, n):
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(signature)):
        num = signature[i]
        total += num
    signature.append(total)
    
    while len(signature) < n:
        for j in range(-1,-4):
            num = signature[j]
            total += num
        signature.append(num)
    return signature
```

```
#Some sample test code:
 
print(tribonacci([1, 1, 1], 10))
print("Correct output: " + "[1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 31, 57, 105]")

print(tribonacci([0, 0, 1], 10))
print("Correct output: " + "[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44]")

print(tribonacci([300, 200, 100], 0))
print("Correct output: " + "[]")
```

UPDATE!

As suggested, I resetted the total count in the while loop by creating a total_2 = 0. I've also added the -1 to the range and changed .append(num) in the while loop block to .append(total_2).

```
def tribonacci(signature, n):
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(signature)):
        num = signature[i]
        total += num
    signature.append(total)
    
    while len(signature) < n:
        total_2 = 0
        for j in range(-1,-4, -1):
            num = signature[j]
            total_2 += num
        signature.append(total_2)
    return signature
```

However, this code doesnt work the 3rd print test code where n = 0. One of the users shared a much shorter code which works for ALL of the test code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `range(-1,-4,-1)`. You need to tell python to go backwards.

Just for the reference, I've implemented your function with a few improvements:

```
def tribonacci(signature, n):
    signature = signature[:n]
    while len(signature) < n:
        signature.append(sum(signature[-3:]))
    return signature
```